# Program compatibilty assistant warning after Unetbootin makes bootable USB

Tags: usb, unetbootin

I have a windows 7 laptop (x64). I am trying to make a bootable USB with ubuntu-14.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso and Unetbootin. I am picking the 'Diskimage' option and providing the path to the iso.

Unetbootin finishes normally but after it exits I get a warning from Windows along the lines of "This program might not have installed correctly". I am wondering whether it is safe to ignore this warning and use the bootable USB to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my hardware?

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure, It is just an additional program compatibility feature in windows. You can ignore that error safely.

Answer (score 0):

when installing ubuntu 18.04 server, from a bootable usb, it shows a warning that the usb was created by unetbootin and it says that users have been reporting that it might not work; actually, I found that unetbootin is a more intuitive method to create a bootable usb than the alternative method in the ubuntu doc;

the only time a bootable usb made with unetbootin did not work for me, was when I selected something other than 0 (zero) for the number of megabytes to preserve state between boots; as long as you leave that set to 0 (default) you can make a bootable usb with unetbootin faster, easier and it works.